# Derivative of cost function with respect to the unitary matrix

Tags: mathematics, variational-quantum-algorithms

Suppose I have a cost function $C = \langle \psi \rvert U^\dagger O U \rvert \psi \rangle$ for a fixed observable $O$ and a fixed state $\rvert \psi \rangle$. I know that usually people take the derivative of the cost function wrt parameters, but here I want to take the derivative of $C$ wrt $U$: $\frac{\partial C}{\partial U} = \langle \psi \rvert \frac{\partial U^\dagger}{\partial U} O U \rvert \psi \rangle + \langle \psi \rvert U^\dagger O \rvert \psi \rangle$, and I am not sure how to deal with $\frac{\partial U^\dagger}{\partial U}$ part. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the origin of the unitary matrix and *how* can it change? (I hope you're not allowing an entirely arbitrary $n$-qubit unitary!)

Answer (score 2):

If I take your questions literally, then the answer is fairly straightforward:
$$
\frac{dU^\dagger}{dU}=-1.
$$
You should think about it this way: we know $UU^\dagger=I$. If $U$ changes by $\delta U$ (small), $U^\dagger$ must change to compensate:
$$
(U+\delta U)(U-\delta U)=I+O(\delta U^2)
$$
Thus, to first order, $U^\dagger$ changes to $U^\dagger-\delta U$.